# Implementing Error handling with a custom error struct and struct validation?

Tags: rest, go

I am extremely new to Golang, and I wrote a small REST API to familiarize myself with the language, and I used Mux as a router. I was wondering if I could get some help in how to implement error handling for my small API, I am having troubles wrapping my head around it. I would like to use an error struct to handle the messages.
below is my code:

```
type Trade struct {
    ClientTradeId string `json:"clientTradeId"`
    Date          int    `json:"date"`
    Quantity      string `json:"quantity"`
    Price         string `json:"price"`
    Ticker        string `json:"ticker"`
}
type InternalTrade struct {
    Id string `json:"Id"`
    Trade *Trade `json:"Trade"`
}

type TradeSubmitted struct {

    TradeId string `json:"TradeId"`
    ClientTradeId string `json:"clientTradeId"`

}

type Error struct {
    Message string `json:"Message"`
}

var trades []InternalTrade

func getTrades(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(trades)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(),500)
    }

}

func getTradeById(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for _, trade := range trades {
        if trade.Id == params["trade_id"] {
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(trade)
            return
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&InternalTrade{})


}

func createTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var trade Trade
    var tradeSubmitted TradeSubmitted

    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&trade)

    internal := InternalTrade{
        Id: strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(1000000)),
        Trade: &trade,
    }


    tradeSubmitted.ClientTradeId = trade.ClientTradeId
    tradeSubmitted.TradeId = internal.Id

    trades = append(trades, internal)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&tradeSubmitted)

}

func deleteTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for idx, trade := range trades {
        if trade.Id == params["trade_id"] {
            trades = append(trades[:idx], trades[idx+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(trades)

}

func updateTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for idx, trade := range trades {
        if trade.Id == params["trade_id"] {
            trades = append(trades[:idx], trades[idx+1:]...)
            var internal InternalTrade
            _  = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&internal.Trade)
            internal.Id = params["trade_id"]
            trades = append(trades, internal)
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(internal)
            return
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    trades = append(trades, InternalTrade{ Id:"1", Trade: &Trade{ClientTradeId: "T-50264430-bc41", Date:20200101,
        Quantity:"100", Price:"10.00", Ticker:"APPL"}})
    trades = append(trades, InternalTrade{ Id:"2", Trade: &Trade{ClientTradeId: "T-99999999-ab14", Date:20200101,
        Quantity:"100", Price:"420.00", Ticker:"TSLA"}})


    router.HandleFunc("/v1/trades", getTrades).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/v1/trades/{trade_id}", getTradeById).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/v1/trades", createTrade).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/v1/trades/{trade_id}", deleteTrade).Methods("DELETE")
    router.HandleFunc("/v1/trades/{trade_id}", updateTrade).Methods("PUT")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

I would like help implementing some error handling on my createTrade function so that I could catch 400 when improper types are passed, 422 when the request is missing fields. 500 for Internal Server error, I would like to pass a custom message using my error struct above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what exactly you looking for. Please describe desired behavior to get concrete suggestion.

Few comments though for your work:

1. Code is mostly clean and idiomatic. Good work!
2. **ALWAYS!!!** check returned errors and handle them as necessary. GO does not rely on try/catch blocks and missed error leaves your app in incorrect state and is not clearly reported.
3. add additional context to errors using `fmt.Errorf` - https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors
4. `http.Error` returns error as plain text. You can make life of your client easier if you return it in the same format (JSON) as successful response
5. GO executes every request (ServeHTTP function) in separate Goroutine.  Concurrent code execution should not mutate shared state. Your `trades` slice is shared and edited from multiple handlers. This can be fine only for test project and should not be used for production.

This is sample code to handle errors in handler:

```golang
func returnError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, code int) {
    var errorData Error
    output, err := json.Marshal(&errorData)
    if err != nil {
        w.Write([]byte("Cannot serialize error"))
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(output)
}

func parseRequest(r *http.Request) (Trade, error) {
    return Trade{}, nil
}

func saveTrade(t Trade) (TradeSubmitted, error) {
    return TradeSubmitted{}, nil
}

func createTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    trade, err := parseRequest(r)
    if err != nil {
        returnError(w, err, 400)
        return
    }

    tradeSubmitted, err := saveTrade(trade)
    if err != nil {
        returnError(w, err, 500)
        return
    }

    output, err := json.Marshal(&tradeSubmitted)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Cannot serialize Trade with id: xxx: %w", err)
        returnError(w, err, 500)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(output)
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you! I will clarify here and edit my post as well. I was hoping someone could help me implement error handling in my above api, specifically in my createTrade function. I would like to handle the errors: 400, 422, 500. How can I catch these errors and return them using my error struct and a status code.

Comment: Would I not use mux anymore with your code snippet?

Comment: I updated code. You continue use mux for routing. My code only covers one function - single route